# JSoup working in IDE but not app server

Tags: java, ubuntu, web-scraping, jsoup, wildfly

I'm new to working with jsoup and scraping/crawling in general. My goal is to pull  pricing, description, and an image from retailers. I'm having an issue with jsoup where when I test it in my IDE (Eclipse) I'm able to retrieve all the elements and data I need, however when I deploy the code to my app server (wildfly running on an ubuntu box) and run the same method from the application interface those elements are not present.  The site connects, but appears to return general information about the site as opposed to the specific product.

To be clear, the scraper works fine with several sites, its only a handful where I meet this behavior.  (On Js heavy sites, I've used selenium standalone server w headless chrome and that works well enough, if a bit slow.)

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE 03/17:  I'm still mystified, I tried switching from jsoup to selenium with headless chrome and still get the exact same behavior.  I don't know if its a function of windows vs linux or in the IDE vs out of the app server or other.  But it works as expected out of the IDE and when it runs from the application, the content from the website just isn't there.

UPDATE 03/20: Pretty sure its a linux vs windows issue of some sort.  I deployed the same version of wildfly on windows and hit the same rest endpoint and it was able to scrape the page(s) in question just fine.

Comment: maybe the IP address of the ubuntu box causes this?

Comment: @luksch - How so?  (I’ve been wondering if there’s some sort of signature inherent with the request out of the app server that flags the call for the website.  Something that suggests to the retailer not to load the requested page.)